Closing connection to the server using "destroy" - Nodemailer in Next JS
Error
[2024-06-12 05:14:48] DEBUG [1NjbSBCk1vc] Resolved smtp.gmail.com as 142.250.102.109 [cache miss]
[2024-06-12 05:16:48] ERROR [1NjbSBCk1vc] Connection timeout
[2024-06-12 05:16:48] DEBUG [1NjbSBCk1vc] Closing connection to the server using "destroy"
[2024-06-12 05:16:48] ERROR Send Error: Connection timeout
My API Route Code
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { mailOptions, transporter } from '@/config/nodemailer'

export async function POST(request) {
  console.log('Yes')
  const requestedData = await request.json()
  const data = requestedData
  console.log(data, 'Mine')
  try {
    await transporter.sendMail({
      ...mailOptions,
      subject: `${data.subject}`,
      text: 'This is an email using nodemail in nodejs',
      html: `<div></div>`,
    })
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Success' })
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: error })
  }
}


mailoptions and transporter code
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer'



export const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  secureConnection: false,
  port: 587,
  requiresAuth: true,
  domains: ['gmail.com', 'googlemail.com'],
  auth: {
    user: 'vigipas2002@gmail.com',
    pass: 'xhkkvlliwqgssxpo',
  },
  logger: true,
  debug: true,
})

export const mailOptions = {
  from: 'vigipas2002@gmail.com',
  to: 'vigifap@gmail.com',
}


Please help in solving this
I want to send email using gmail & nodemailer
